# Missing column schema validation

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jhipster

I have a big issue, I spent two days fighting with this problem.
I want to add a new relationship between two entities. The first entity is `User`, the second entity is `UserType`. I want to create `@OneToMany` relationship, so I add this part of the code to class `User`:

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<UserType> userTypes;
```

and I also add to the second class:

```
@ManyToOne
private User user;
```

Of course, I create a new column which called `user_id` on `user_type` table and I add foreign key on this column.

But when I am trying to run my app I get this error:

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:377)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:955)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:880)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [user_id] in table [user_type]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateTable(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.validateTables(GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:877)
    ... 66 more
```

I am using Jhipster, what should I do to find solution? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Class `UserType`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_type")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class UserType implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
    private String type;

    @ManyToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_type_event",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_types_id", referencedColumnName="ID"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="events_id", referencedColumnName="ID"))
    private Set<Event> events = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_type_prelection",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_types_id", referencedColumnName="ID"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="prelections_id", referencedColumnName="ID"))
    private Set<Prelection> prelections = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    }
```

Class `User`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jhi_user")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class User extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = Constants.LOGIN_REGEX)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @JsonIgnore
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 60, max = 60)
    @Column(name = "password_hash",length = 60)
    private String password;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "first_name", length = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "last_name", length = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @Email
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(length = 100, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean activated = false;

    @Size(min = 2, max = 5)
    @Column(name = "lang_key", length = 5)
    private String langKey;

    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "activation_key", length = 20)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String activationKey;

    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "reset_key", length = 20)
    private String resetKey;

    @Column(name = "reset_date", nullable = true)
    private ZonedDateTime resetDate = null;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "jhi_user_authority",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "authority_name", referencedColumnName = "name")})
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<PersistentToken> persistentTokens = new HashSet<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<UserType> userTypes;
    }
```

Comment: It seems OneToMany annotation should be in the UserType class, and ManyToOne in the User class. Lets look at full code of User and UserType classes.

Comment: But why? `User` can contain many `UserTypes`  so why `User` class has to have only one `UserType` and `UserType` has to contain set of `User`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change code in User class from this:

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<UserType> userTypes;
}
```

to this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_type")
private UserType userType;
```

and delete this code in UserType class:

```
@ManyToOne
private User user;
}
```